# Pandas Datafram JSON data extract and join HTML tag

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi below the datafram each row has JSON array data on metadata.reference column, am trying to create datafram without JSON array and want to add  HTML tag.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {
      "serverid": "admin@admin.com",
      "ipaddress": "10.10.10.10",
      "metadata.reference": [
        {
          "@source": "elsa",
          "@ref_id": "ELSA-2022-9781",
          "@ref_url": "https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html"
        },
        {
          "@source": "CVE",
          "@ref_id": "CVE-2020-0466",
          "@ref_url": "https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "serverid": "admin2@admin.com",
        "ipaddress": "10.10.10.10",
        "metadata.reference": [
          {
            "@source": "elsa",
            "@ref_id": "ELSA-2022-9781",
            "@ref_url": "https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html"
          },
          {
            "@source": "CVE",
            "@ref_id": "CVE-2020-0466",
            "@ref_url": "https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html"
          }
        ]
      }

])
```

Current Output

```
    serverid          ipaddress     metadata.reference
0   admin@admin.com   10.10.10.10   [{'@source': 'elsa', '@ref_id': 'ELSA-2022-978...
1   admin2@admin.com  10.10.10.10   [{'@source': 'elsa', '@ref_id': 'ELSA-2022-978...
```

Looking for

```
    serverid          ipaddress     metadata.reference
0   admin@admin.com   10.10.10.10   <a herf="<https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html>">ELSA-2022-9781</a>;<a herf="<https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html">CVE-2020-0466</a>;
1   admin2@admin.com  10.10.10.10   <a herf="<https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html>">ELSA-2022-9781</a>;<a herf="<https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html>">CVE-2020-0466</a>;
```

Comment: NB. I think you meant `href` not `herf` ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

```
URL = '<a herf="{@ref_url}">{@ref_id}</a>'

df['metadata.reference'] = [';'.join([URL.format(**d) for d in l])
                            for l in df['metadata.reference']]
```

If the column can also contain objects other than dictionaries (thanks @Tranbi):

```
df['metadata.reference'] = [';'.join([URL.format(**d) for d in l
                                      if isinstance(d, dict)])
                            for l in df['metadata.reference']]
```

Output:

```
           serverid    ipaddress                                                                                                                                            metadata.reference
0   admin@admin.com  10.10.10.10  <a herf="https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html">ELSA-2022-9781</a>;<a herf="https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html">CVE-2020-0466</a>
1  admin2@admin.com  10.10.10.10  <a herf="https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2022-9781.html">ELSA-2022-9781</a>;<a herf="https://linux.oracle.com/cve/CVE-2020-0466.html">CVE-2020-0466</a>
```

Comment: I like the unpacking of d :-D But why would you say it's more flexible? They really look equivalent to me.. +1

Comment: @Tranbi because you can just change the values in the `URL` string without needing to worry about the proper construction of the f-string and the name of the dictionary. IMO this makes it easier to customize ;)

Comment: Ok I see. Less editing in case of refactoring/renaming of `d`. Nice touch when dealing with more complex strings :-)

Comment: its working for testing data, but getting TypeError where calling realtime data, i can seen i some of rows has NA data. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 URL = '<a herf="{@ref_url}">{@ref_id}</a>'
----> 2 df_XML_ALL['metadata.reference'] = [';'.join([URL.format(**d) for d in l])for l in df_XML_ALL['metadata.reference']]
      3 df_XML_ALL
TypeError: str.format() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Comment: Interesting, what is the output of `{k for l in df_XML_ALL['metadata.reference'] for d in l for k in d}`?

Comment: {'@ref_id', '@ref_url', '@source', 'A', 'N'}

Comment: I don't see what could be wrong. Can you provide a subsample of your DataFrame that triggers the error?

Comment: Do you get an error with @Tranbi's answer? Maybe you don't have a dictionary in all lists?

Comment: {
"serverid": "admin@admin.com"
"metadata.advisory.severity": "Medium",
    "metadata.reference": [
      {
        "@source": "USN",
        "@ref_url": "https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4126-1",
        "@ref_id": "USN-4126-1"
      },
      {
        "@source": "CVE",
        "@ref_url": "https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2015-9383",
        "@ref_id": "CVE-2015-9383"
      }
    ]
}

i have more than 10K block like this.

Comment: One element of the `metadata.reference` list is a string. Replace the comprehension with `[URL.format(**d) for d in l if isinstance(d, dict)]`

Comment: Thanks Tranbi and mozway, you guys save my day.. working perfect.

Comment: @Bandhala you're welcome. Don't forget to vote for Tranbi's answer as well ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can create the html from the dict by applying your own function:

```
def lst_to_html(lst):
    return ';'.join([f'<a herf="{d["@ref_url"]}">{d["@ref_id"]}</a>' for d in lst])

df['metadata.reference'] = df['metadata.reference'].apply(lst_to_html)
```

Comment: Almost the same approach ;) +1 (NB. I still prefer `format` that is more flexible than a f-string here)

Comment: current scenario data are in DataFram Column , am not sure about list approach

Comment: The lists here are the individual elements of `df['metadata.reference']` (`[{'@source': 'elsa', '@ref_id': 'ELSA-2022-978...`)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid floating error, replaced with NA.

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), "NA")
URL = '<a href="{@ref_url}">{@ref_id}</a>'
df['metadata.reference'] = [';'.join([URL.format(**d) for d in l if isinstance(d, dict)])for l in df['metadata.reference']]
```